# Wrap/break equations text when exporting to PDF

Tags: math-mode, pdf, margins

So I just finished writing my homework in Lyx and I was about to print it after exporting to PDF, but I noticed that some of the centered equations were too long and their most-right part is exceeding the right margin of the PDF page.

I saw that I can use AMSmath to solve it but for that it seems like I need to manually copy all of the equations to AMSmath boxes.

Is there any way to solve it with a quick PDF-export preprocess? edit some setting?

This is one of the long equations (gaussian elimination):

```
\L{
\[
\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 2\\
8 & 0 & 2\\
18 & 0 & 2
\end{matrix}\right)\to\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
4 & 0 & 1\\
9 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)\to\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
4 & 0 & 1\\
5 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\to\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
4 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\to\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\to\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\to\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\to\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)
\]
}
```

and as you can see in the PDF it's being cut right before the end: 
[image: pdf equation]
thanks...

Comment: Better than you add your PDF result too, so we can see the problem clearly.

Comment: Does Lyz support `\usepackage{showframe}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\multline` in package `amsmath` to divide long expressions taking more than one line.

```
\begin{multline} 
a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m\\ 
+n+o+p+q+r+s+t+w+x+y+z=0 
\end{multline}
```

It will divide that long equation into 2 line.

Or you can use `gather` environment (`gather*`) if you need a non-numbered equation).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 2\\
8 & 0 & 2\\
18 & 0 & 2
\end{matrix}\right)\to\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
4 & 0 & 1\\
9 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)\to\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
4 & 0 & 1\\
5 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\to\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
4 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\to\\ %<= this where the eq will be splitted
\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\to\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\to\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)\to\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

I think this is not bad to show the Gaussian Method.

[image: MWE]

Comment: But it means I have to add these tags for every single equation in my document, right?

Comment: @gbi1977 yes of course, you can also use `gather` environment to get same as `multline` but the splitted equation will be centered. You can check `amsmath` documentation for more information.

Comment: I acutally used all of these environments right now and it still won't help, the equations exceed the right margin. the best way I found is to add a new line with CTRL+ENTER and copy to tail of the eqaution there. But I thought there should be at least one simple setting to wrap the eqautions during pdflatex export...